# Docker image DNS issues

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, composer-php, github-api

I am trying to build a Docker container for my new project and seem to be getting odd GitHub DNS resolution issues while attempting to run the docker build command.

I can't run the composer install command on my local machine because I have an outdated version of PHP which is why I am attempting to use a container.

Multiple other project on my personal machine don't have an issue installing composer dependences, but when I try and build the Docker Image I get several (but not all) errors for packages that are as follows

```
  - Syncing phar-io/version (3.1.0) into cache
Failed to download slim/psr7 from dist: curl error 6 while downloading https://api.github.com/repos/slimphp/Slim-Psr7/zipball/0dca983ca32a26f4a91fb11173b7b9eaee29e9d6: Could not resolve host: api.github.com
Now trying to download from source
  - Syncing slim/psr7 (1.4) into cache

 120/120 [============================] 100%The following exception probably indicates you have misconfigured DNS resolver(s)

                                                                                                                                                                                              
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                                                                        
  curl error 6 while downloading https://api.github.com/repos/phingofficial/phing-composer-configurator/zipball/a151e1804dd4c946969cfb78bed1a0e12f52ad34: Could not resolve host: api.github.com
```

Is this something I have misconfigured in Docker, the DockerFile, or my Composer JSON?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is an issue with my specific version of Docker Desktop for Mac.

DNS resolution fails in Docker for Mac in versions prior to 3.1.0 periodically due to a buggy MacOS API  They are using to pass DNS resolution to the guest. The solution is to update to a new version of Docker For Mac.

I've provided a summary of the issue should anyone need resolution in the future. More information can be found here

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5020